# Not correct image rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have resizable Image, zoom screen

[image]

**Code:**

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageBackground"];
UIImage * imageBackground = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 13)
                                                      resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
[self.backgroundImageView setImage:imageBackground];
```

But in application rendering :

[image]

**What could be the problem ?**

**Update :**

Original image :

[image]

Finish image, resize image, with save left and right 13 points:

[image]

Resize work, but left and right 13 points rendering not correct (look first and second image).

Comment: We don't know the original size of your image, You don't explaint what effect you want (original image, image you want). It`s difficult to help you with this information, but It's good thing start with this:  UIImage * imageBackground = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                                      resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];